# Sorting the data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, join

I want to match a product number (column 1) and a year (column 2) for Country A with the same product and year for Country B to be able to subtract the corresponding trade numbers (column 3 minus column 6) for the countries in that year and in that product. When no counterpart is found I want that post to be thrown out.

In the example in the link below I have manually done this until row 22 (except subtracting the trade figures). The row below (23) for instance says that product 030420 was traded in 1995 at value 2.823, but no trade in that product in that year is recorded in country B, so that post I want deleted. Correspondingly, in Country B, trade of product 030420 is recorded in 1994, but there is no counterpart in country A, so that post also should be deleted.

Even though the data in the example below is shown in excel (I tried to solve this in excel but it got tricky) I now have the data stored in a matrix in Matlab and want to write a code for it, but I'm quite new to Matlab/coding. In words it might be something like:

- IF first entry in column 1 = any entry in column 4
- then also IF first entry in column 2 = any entry in column 5, subtract the trade figure (column 6, wherever it ends up being found) from the first entry in column 3.
- If no match is found I'd like the program to throw out that post as described above.

And then of course repeat the procedure for the rest of the sample.

Example:

[image: http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/1214/skrmavbild20110609kl092.png]

If anyone feels like reading this shorter essay and have any suggestions it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this solution, I will be using **[Dataset Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/bqziht7-1.html#bqzihxq)** from the Statistics Toolbox.

Consider the following two sample CSV files (similar to your Excel file, but I divided the two countries into separate files):

#### countryA.csv

```
ProductCode,Year,TradeValue
011111,1992,5.934
011111,1999,7.05
022222,2002,5.2
033333,2005,16.6
033333,2006,55
```

#### countryB.csv

```
ProductCode,Year,TradeValue
011111,1992,24.5
011111,1999,25
033333,2005,33.11
033333,2006,44.92
044444,2010,10.8
```

The code below reads the two datasets, and performs an inner [join](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dataset.join.html) using (ProductCode,Year) as row keys, then we compute the difference of the two trade values for matching rows:

```
%# read datasets (note we are reading ProductCode/Year as strings to preserve leading zeros)
dA = dataset('File','countryA.csv', 'Delimiter',',', 'Format','%s %s %f','ReadVarNames',true);
dB = dataset('File','countryB.csv', 'Delimiter',',', 'Format','%s %s %f','ReadVarNames',true);

%# inner join (keep only rows that exist in both datasets)
ds = join(dA, dB, 'keys',{'ProductCode' 'Year'}, 'type','inner', 'MergeKeys',true);

%# add a new variable for the difference
dsTradeDiff = dataset(ds.TradeValue_left - ds.TradeValue_right, 'VarNames','TradeDifference');
ds = cat(2, ds, dsTradeDiff);
```

The resulting dataset:

```
ds = 
    ProductCode     Year          TradeValue_left    TradeValue_right    TradeDifference
    '011111'        '1992'        5.934               24.5               -18.566        
    '011111'        '1999'         7.05                 25                -17.95        
    '033333'        '2005'         16.6              33.11                -16.51        
    '033333'        '2006'           55              44.92                 10.08
```

---

**EDIT:** This is an alternative way to achieve the same as above, using only basic built-in MATLAB functions:

```
%# read countryA
fid = fopen('countryA.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f', 'Delimiter',',', 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
[prodCodeA yearA tradeValA] = deal(C{:});

%# read countryB
fid = fopen('countryB.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %f', 'Delimiter',',', 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
[prodCodeB yearB tradeValB] = deal(C{:});

%# build rows merged-keys
keysA = strcat(prodCodeA,yearA);
keysB = strcat(prodCodeB,yearB);

%# match rows
[idx1 loc1] = ismember(keysA,keysB);
[idx2 loc2] = ismember(keysB,keysA);

%# compute result for intersection of rows
tradeDiff = tradeValA(loc2(idx2)) - tradeValB(loc1(idx1))
```

with the same result:

```
tradeDiff =
      -18.566
       -17.95
       -16.51
        10.08
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. Creating .csv files with excel for mac was trouble but worked out in the end, just "delimiter" had to be ';' instead of ',' for me.

Comment: @Oscar: glad I could help. Consider marking it as accepted answer if you feel this has solved your problem...

Comment: I also have a dataset containing tariffs on products and I wanted to add a column "tariffs" in "ds" above with the tariffs for the ProductCodes they belong to. It went ok using the join method again but I noticed that it doesn't work when the datasets are of different lengths, which will often be the case for me. Any ideas? Fill with zeros to make them equal somehow?

Comment: I'm also curious to the 'MergeKeys' you included above, didn't get that to work and removed it from the code.