# Matlab: Join datasets by not exact but similar values

Tags: matlab, join

I have two example datasets, A and B below, that I want to join in Matlab to create C. The keys will be 'product' and 'year', but the problem is that the product number in dataset B only matches the one in A by the first 4 digits. Is there a way to join 'almost' matching numbers in this way?

```
 
A       
product tariff  year
202341  2       1999
202341  4       2000
202341  20      2008
202355  9       1999
202355  16      2000
438811  0       1999
438891  8       1999
438891  3       2001
671212  15      2005
671260  10      2005
```

and

```
B       
product avg_tariff  year
2023    5,5         1999
2023    10          2000
2023    20          2008
4388    4           1999
4388    3           2001
6712    12,5        2005
```

are joined to produce matrix C

```
C           
product tariff  year    avg_tariff
202341  2       1999    5,5
202341  4       2000    10
202341  20      2008    20
202355  9       1999    5,5
202355  16      2000    10
438811  0       1999    4
438891  8       1999    4
438891  3       2001    3
671212  15      2005    12,5
671260  10      2005    12,5
```

Thanks in advance

Oscar

Comment: why matlab? a lot easier in excel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load the product array and treat it as strings using textscan:

```
fidA = fopen('A.txt');
fidB = fopen('B.txt');
A = textscan(fidA,'%s%s%s','delimiter',' ');
B = textscan(fidB,'%s%s%s','delimiter',' ');
fclose(fidA);
fclose(fidB);
```

keep only the first 4 chars of product in A

```
for i = 1:length(A{1})
   rowKeyA{i} = [A{1}{i}(1:4),A{3}{i}]; %product(1:4),year
end
for i = 1:length(B{1})
   rowKeyB{i} = [B{1}{i},B{3}{i}]; %product,year
end
```

now just find matches between rowKeyA and rowKeyB

```
for i = 1:length(rowKeyA)
    j = find(strcmp(rowKeyB,rowKeyA{i}),1);
    if(j)
       fprintf('%s %s %s\n',rowKeyA{i},A{2},B{2});
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is related to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438193/matlab-sorting-data-issue) one of yours I answered, I will reuse the code and update it to the new data:

#### a.csv

```
product tariff  year
202341  2       1999
202341  4       2000
202341  20      2008
202355  9       1999
202355  16      2000
438811  0       1999
438891  8       1999
438891  3       2001
671212  15      2005
671260  10      2005
```

#### b.csv

```
product avg_tariff  year
2023    5.5         1999
2023    10          2000
2023    20          2008
4388    4           1999
4388    3           2001
6712    12.5        2005
```

#### MATLAB code

(using the Dataset class from the Statistics Toolbox):

```
%# read A, and build dataset
fid = fopen('a.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s%f%f', 'Delimiter',' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true, 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
dA = dataset({C{1} 'product'}, {C{2} 'tariff'}, {C{3} 'year'});

%# read B, and build dataset
fid = fopen('b.csv','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s%f%f', 'Delimiter',' ', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne',true, 'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
dB = dataset({C{1} 'product'}, {C{2} 'avg_tariff'}, {C{3} 'year'});

%# truncate productA
dA.productLong = dA.product;
dA.product = cellfun(@(s)s(:,1:end-2), cellstr(dA.product), 'UniformOutput',false);

%# inner join (keep only rows that exist in both datasets)
ds = join(dA, dB, 'keys',{'product' 'year'}, 'type','inner', 'MergeKeys',true);

%# restore the long product number as first column, and sort by it
ds.product = ds.productLong;
ds.productLong = [];
ds = sortrows(ds, 'product')
```

The result as expected:

```
ds = 
    product         tariff    year    avg_tariff
    '202341'         2        1999     5.5      
    '202341'         4        2000      10      
    '202341'        20        2008      20      
    '202355'         9        1999     5.5      
    '202355'        16        2000      10      
    '438811'         0        1999       4      
    '438891'         8        1999       4      
    '438891'         3        2001       3      
    '671212'        15        2005    12.5      
    '671260'        10        2005    12.5
```